# Variable input voltage relay circuit

Tags: relay

I'm trying to devise a way to switch 12 V, 25 A using a relay. The problem: the trigger has two states, the OFF position 4.8 V, 0.3 A and the ON position 25 V, 0.3 A.

I tried with a regular 24 V relay, but 4.8 V is too high for the relay to release. I could use a 10 kΩ resistor to drop the voltage in half and a 12 V relay, but I am not sure if that would be the best way. Any better solutions?

Comment: Draw a circuit please.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest, most zero-effort solution would be something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKvrRs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will give the relay 0 V when the input is at 4.8 V, and about 19 V when the input is at 24 V. This is dependent on your relay working at 19 V, which isn't too uncommon for 24 V relays; just check that the "must actuate voltage" is less than 19 V. D1 has to be rated for the relay's coil current, naturally, but 24 V relays don't usually need much current, so your standard 1 W zener should do fine. Get a 3 W one if you're worried. I used a 5.1 V zener because it's the most commonly available standard value higher than 4.8 V, but you could even use a lower voltage one than 4.8 V if you make sure it drops a 4.8 V input to below the relay's rated "must release voltage".

If, on the other hand, this won't work, there are a number of more complex things you can do. The one that immediately comes to mind for me is essentially the same trick again, applied to a transistor switch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOerdp.png)</sup>

The resistance of R1 needs to be chosen depending on your zener diode and transistor. D1 is a 10 V zener here, but could be anything between 4.8 and 24 V as long as you account for it in the calculations.

There are other things you could do, of course, with comparators or more complex transistor circuits. But this is simple, easy, and cheap.

Comment: +1 You can also get 18V relays off-the-shelf and not have to worry about the relay not pulling in at high Ta. They're used in HVAC, for example.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Oh, that's good to know! I've never even heard of an 18 V relay.

Comment: 12V relay and 12V zener is also a good option, giving more leeway regarding the voltages.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjsgdz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should provide the full 0-24 V to the relay coil. But for some reason the CSV does not seem to work. I'm used to LTspice, which does not use commas to separate time and voltage points.